# Were the players able to communicate with the outside world?

Tags: sword-art-online

Were the players of SAO able to communicate with the outside world?  Could they get any info from the outside world?

We don't see anything in season 1 to support this, but they did have information brokers, and I think it was hinted that they brokers could get information from the outside, for example news.

Answer (score 3):

> Were the players of SAO able to communicate with the outside world? Could they get any info from the outside world?

If I remember correctly, no, they cannot communicate with the outside world nor was it hinted that they were able to. Regarding the information brokers, I think they only deal with information inside the SAO world, not with information in the real world. As seen [here](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Argo), Argo sold information between players but **the information sold was restricted to information found in the game world.**

Answer (score 0):

They definitely could not have. Then none of the players would of panicked as much, because they could have contacted their families.